# Git Blame: View all Lines Authored by Specific User

Tags: git, blame

Can git blame be used to view all lines in the current codebase committed by a single user?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Closest I could get was

```
git log -p --author=<author> <filename>
```

or

```
git blame <filename> | grep <authorname>
```

Comment: Ended up using the second one inside a for-loop: `for file in sourcedir/*; do git blame -- $file | grep <authorname> >> blame.txt; done`